# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk' , how I can get the Id of the post from home view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How I can get the pk of objects in home view, I try to make personal blog with posts and this posts include comments, I tried to get the post pk in order to get the comments that related to this post but I failed
Firstly I tried to get th pk by add it in   `def home_view(request, pk)` but this template in home page `www.mywebsite.com` that's mean as I know, I cann't pass pk to the url so that's failed with me

#### My qustion is how I can get the Id of the post from home view?

My home View

```
post = []
for u in users:
  p = Account.objects.get(username=u)
            posts = p.post_set.all()

post.append(posts)
  if len(video):  
 video = sorted(chain(*video), reverse=True, key=lambda video:         video.created_date)

# here I tried to get the pk
comma = Post.objects.all()
our_post = Post.objects.get(pk=comma.pk)
comment = PostCommentIDF.objects.filter(post=our_post)
```

My Post Model

```
class Post(models.Model):
 author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    photo_article = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=get_poster_filepath)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My Comment Model

```
class PostCommentIDF(MPTTModel):

post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='pos_com')
parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='post_children')
author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
content = models.TextField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

The Home View Url

```
path('', home_screen_view, name='home'),
```

Comment: `comma = Post.objects.all()` returns `QuerySet`. It's something like list or array. Attribute `pk` is on each item in that 'array' not on array itself.

Comment: @zelenyjan feel free to post it as an answer..

Comment: @zelenyjan Is there is way to take the post item pk and used it in the comment like that `comment = PostCommentIDF.objects.filter(post=post.pk)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really not sure what's your goal by let me try it...

`comma = Post.objects.all()` returns `QuerySet`. It's something like list or array. Attribute `pk` is on each item in that 'array' not on array itself.

If you have `QuerySet` (list of your posts) you can loop over it:

```py
comma = Post.objects.all()  # returns all posts
for post in comma:  # now post is single post
    our_post = Post.objects.get(pk=post.pk)  # now you can call 'pk' because post is single post and not QuerySet... this line is not needed because you already have post
    comment = PostCommentIDF.objects.filter(post=post)  # now get comments for that one post
```

EDIT:
How to use in view and template:

```py
post_with_comments = []

comma = Post.objects.all()  # returns all posts
for post in comma:  # now post is single post
    our_post = Post.objects.get(pk=post.pk)  # now you can call 'pk' because post is single post and not QuerySet... this line is not needed because you already have post
    comment = PostCommentIDF.objects.filter(post=post)  # now get comments for that one post
    post_with_comments.append({"post": post, "comments": comment})

context = {"items": post_with_comments}
return context
```

and then in the template you loop over all `post_with_comments`

```html
{% for item in items %}
  {{ item.post }}
  {{ item.comments.count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hello Thank you for you answer. I tried this to for example return the number of the comments and it return 0 by this way `{{comment.count}}`

Comment: Try to add `print(comment.count())` after `comment = PostCommentIDF.objects.filter(post=post)` if you have any comment in database you will see different count then 0 for at least one post. From your comment is impossible to tell if 0 is OK or not

Comment: It's work but in just when  the print inside the for loop, but when the it out the for loop it return 0 how I can let it possible because I want to pass it to the context to the template? and thank you I will consider this as accepted answer

Comment: @Ahmed I updated answer include template sample

Comment: Thank you it is return `'set' object has no attribute '_mptt_meta'
` but I think it is problem related to mptt comments model